# Web API 2: how to return JSON with camelCased property names, on objects and their sub-objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the answers. I am on a new project and it looks like I've finally got to the bottom of this: It looks like the following code was in fact to blame:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage GetHttpSuccessResponse(object response, HttpStatusCode code = HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        StatusCode = code,
        Content = response != null ? new JsonContent(response) : null
    };
}
```

elsewhere...

```
public JsonContent(object obj)
{
    var encoded = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore } );
    _value = JObject.Parse(encoded);

    Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
}
```

I had overlooked the innocuous looking JsonContent assuming it was WebAPI but no.

This is used *everywhere*... Can I just be the first to say, wtf? Or perhaps that should be "Why are they doing this?"

---

*original question follows*

One would have thought this would be a simple config setting, but it's eluded me for too long now.

I have looked at various solutions and answers:

https://gist.github.com/rdingwall/2012642

doesn't seem to apply to latest WebAPI version...

The following doesn't seem to work - property names are still PascalCased.

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;

json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
json.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;

json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Mayank's answer here: [CamelCase JSON WebAPI Sub-Objects (Nested objects, child objects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370619/camelcase-json-webapi-sub-objects-nested-objects-child-objects) seemed like an unsatisfactory but workable answer until I realised these attributes would have to be added to generated code as we are using linq2sql...

Any way to do this automatically? This 'nasty' has plagued me for a long time now.

Comment: http://www.matskarlsson.se/blog/serialize-net-objects-as-camelcase-json

Comment: Also there is a reason why Linq2SQL produces partial classes. Also...Linq2SQL WTF?!

Comment: Thanks but this link is for MVC, it's Web API 2 I'm using, and I'm not sure if there's a way to set the content-type like this, and return a string, but if there is it doesn't seem like quite the right solution.. Thanks for the tip about partial classes too, but is it possible to add an attribute to a property defined in the other part of the partial?

Comment: Also yes, linq2sql wtf... not my decision :)

Comment: the result is the same, the only difference is where you inject the `JsonSerializer`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274625/how-to-set-custom-jsonserializersettings-for-json-net-in-mvc-4-web-api

Comment: yes it is possible, but not in C#. You'd probably want to achieve it using some sort of compile time AOP like PostSharp or Fody.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Putting it all together you get...

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
}
```

Comment: Definitely the way to turn it on, but my problem was that this setting was being ignored (see my answer)

Comment: @Tom erm...Tom did you know what `json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;` does? It tells WebAPI not to use `Json.Net` for serialization. >_<

Comment: Yes, I do now. However, there was also an additional problem. I verified this. See my answer. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552567/web-api-2-how-to-return-json-with-camelcased-property-names-on-objects-and-the/28553295#28553295

Comment: In fact, on closer inspection it turns out that I was mistaken in my earlier conclusion. See my update.

Answer (score 32):

This is what worked for me:

```
internal static class ViewHelpers
{
    public static JsonSerializerSettings CamelCase
    {
        get
        {
            return new JsonSerializerSettings {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/campaign/list")]
public IHttpActionResult ListExistingCampaigns()
{
    var domainResults = _campaignService.ListExistingCampaigns();
    return Json(domainResults, ViewHelpers.CamelCase);
}
```

The class `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` comes from `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` in [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.

Comment: This approach is very useful when one wants to have the camelCasing only for some APIs, not for all the APIs in the application. (Y)

Answer (score 17):

It turns out that

```
return Json(result);
```

was the culprit, causing the serialization process to ignore the camelcase setting. And that

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, Request.GetConfiguration());
```

was the droid I was looking for.

Also

```
json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
```

Was putting a spanner in the works and turned out to be NOT the droid I was looking for.

Comment: This is actually the wrong answer. See my update in the question.

Comment: I actually found this to be the case. When returning `Json(result)`, I was seeing everything in PascalCase, but when I returned `Content(StatusCode, result)` it worked as expected.

Answer (score 14):

All the above answers didn't work for me with Owin Hosting and Ninject. Here's what worked for me:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Get the ninject kernel from our IoC.
        var kernel = IoC.GetKernel();

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // More config settings and OWIN middleware goes here.

        // Configure camel case json results.
        ConfigureCamelCase(config);

        // Use ninject middleware.
        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel);

        // Use ninject web api.
        app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure all JSON responses to have camel case property names.
    /// </summary>
    private void ConfigureCamelCase(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        // This next line is not required for it to work, but here for completeness - ignore data contracts.
        jsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
        var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
#if DEBUG
        // Pretty json for developers.
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
#else
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
#endif
        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

The key difference is: new HttpConfiguration() rather than GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.

Comment: For self-hosting via OWIN, this is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Owin, this solution works perfectly, but only after you tear all your hair out!

Answer (score 14):

Code of WebApiConfig:

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
    
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
    
            //This line sets json serializer's ContractResolver to CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver, 
            //  so API will return json using camel case
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    
        }
    }
```

Make sure your API Action Method returns data in following way and you have installed latest version of Json.Net/Newtonsoft.Json Installed:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage List()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = /*write code to fetch your result - type can be anything*/;
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In 2023 using .NET Framework 4.7.2 with WebAPI 2 (with all up-to-date nuggets) the config.Formatters.JsonFormatter line is all I needed to do to convert everything to camelCase (even Swagger OpenAPI figured out the camel case configuration automatically). Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In your Owin Startup add this line...

```
 public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var webApiConfiguration = ConfigureWebApi();            
        app.UseWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
    }

    private HttpConfiguration ConfigureWebApi()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // ADD THIS LINE HERE AND DONE
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(); 

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        return config;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an obscure one, when the route attribute did not match the GET url but the GET url matched the method name, the jsonserializer camel case directive would be ignored e.g.

> http://website/api/geo/geodata

```
//uppercase fail cakes
[HttpGet]
[Route("countries")]
public async Task<GeoData> GeoData()
{
    return await geoService.GetGeoData();
}

//lowercase nomnomnom cakes
[HttpGet]
[Route("geodata")]
public async Task<GeoData> GeoData()
{
    return await geoService.GetGeoData();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it following ways.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet()]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllItems(int moduleId)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;

            try
            {
                List<ItemInfo> itemList = GetItemsFromDatabase(moduleId);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, itemList, config);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WebApi with Breeze and I ran the same issue when trying to execute a non-breeze action  into a breeze controller. I tried to use the apprach Request.GetConfiguration but the same result. So, when I access the object returned by Request.GetConfiguration I realize that the serializer used by request is the one that breeze-server use to make it's magic. Any way, I resolved my issue creating a different HttpConfiguration:

```
public static HttpConfiguration BreezeControllerCamelCase
        {
            get
            {
                var config = new HttpConfiguration();
                var jsonSerializerSettings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
                jsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                jsonSerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;

                return config;
            }
        }
```

and passing it as parameter at Request.CreateResponse as follow:

```
return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, WebApiHelper.BreezeControllerCamelCase);
```