# Why Web Api can't populate ViewModel object with the values posted from browser by Restangular?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

It is a basic topic and there are many answers in the topic, but I cannot see why my case does not work as it is expected.

**The problem**:
moduleContract variable always null and exception is thrown.

**What I did so far**:

- read as much answers here as possible to find the solution - no success
- check my other solution, which is working fine, and compare to this - there is no difference, or I haven't find the difference
- request help from my supersmart dev peers - the couldn't help
- checking official tutorials - no success

**The controller**:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("add")]
public string AddModuleScreen([FromBody] KendoModuleScreenViewModel moduleContract)
{
    if (moduleContract == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    //return _digitalLibraryApplication.AddNewModuleScreen(moduleContract);
    return "asd";
}
```

**The WebApiConfig**:

```cs
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);

}
```

**The ViewModel**: (don't ask why the ModuleId is an object, it is due to Kendo UI)

```cs
public class KendoModuleScreenViewModel
{
    public int ModuleScreenId { get; set; }

    public int ModuleScreenIsEnabled { get; set; }

    public string ModuleScreenName { get; set; }

    public string ModuleScreenRoute { get; set; }

    public string ModuleScreenDesc { get; set; }

    public int ModuleScreenSortNo { get; set; }

    public KendoModuleViewModel ModuleId { get; set; }

}
```

**The request**:

```
Request URL:http://dilib.local/services/webapi/administration/modulescreens/add
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80

Request URL:http://dilib.local/services/webapi/administration/modulescreens/add
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80

POST /services/webapi/administration/modulescreens/add HTTP/1.1
Host: dilib.local
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 322
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://dilib.local
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Bearer z1rjKoxXM2BjuJXpEWMN3hi4FRFIkh1Qy4U4NSfhkZ52d8lLHEBVkk-ILJ4QVYlXlIV_gNbFPI0ys91CFMytGs9pppIxbFLpStaq4pwm8PhIeOIXhIuhpC0XEQegNyMhYCj0EBQ5rdBiQIApBcUh4MvIfpCadOcrQChTUs2emKPmFYbEgSE-c6vRdLBe8HYwyYJgOndYHiVdQQsoNKd6rQ
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
DNT: 1
Referer: http://dilib.local/ui.spa/administration/modules_screens
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,hu;q=0.6

{
    "moduleScreenId": 0,
    "moduleScreenName": "asdasd",
    "moduleScreenDesc": "asdasd",
    "moduleScreenSortNo": 0,
    "moduleScreenRoute": "asdasd",
    "moduleScreenIsEnabled": true,
    "moduleId": {
        "moduleName": "Blog",
        "moduleDesc": "Publish your thoughts",
        "moduleRoute": "blog",
        "moduleSortNo": 2,
        "moduleScreenDtos": null,
        "moduleIsEnabled": 1,
        "moduleId": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but by default the JSON formatter in Web API uses Pascal case naming convention. So try posing your object with variable names starting with uppercase letter and it should work. If you still want to use camel case (which is preferred for JavaScript) look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552567/web-api-2-how-to-return-json-with-camelcased-property-names-on-objects-and-the

Comment: Unfortunately not. I created a particular javascript object having the same camelcased property names as the POCO does have and the variable in the controller still null. I guess the issue might be around Autofac, OWIN, OAuth and other nasty things.

Comment: Bah... There were two mistakes. First the object I posted to the WebApi was not fit for the ViewModel - the posted object had a boolean value, the ViewModel had the same property as integer. The second problem was that you mentioned. If you write an answer I'll accept it!