# how to force camelCase response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, visual-studio-2017, self-host-webapi

I am attempting to force a camelCase response with the following line in my ConfigureApp method:

```
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

The entire method:

```
        public static void ConfigureApp(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

And I'm returning the following response from my controller:

```
    public object Get()
    {
        var result = new { name = "alex", number = 1, lastname = "smith" };

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

The response I am getting is:

```
{"name":"alex","number":1,"lastname":"smith"}
```

The response I am expecting is:

```
{"name":"alex","number":1,"lastName":"smith"}
```

**How do I force camelCase response (lastname vs lastName)?**

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as the configuration is exactly inline with the suggested approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552567/web-api-2-how-to-return-json-with-camelcased-property-names-on-objects-and-the

Comment: @MeggieLuski if you want lastname to be lastName, then in c# your property name should be LastName not Lastname.