# JSON data fails to map to my exported interface?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, serialization

I can't bind my Angular HTML to my `devices` array because there is a mismatch between what I am expecting the object to look like. I want to bind to `device.modelName` but it fails because the object I'm actually getting back has the property `ModelName` without camelCase!

Googling a solution I saw that I should use *type assertion* so I did by adding `<DeviceStatus[]>` resulting in the line `<DeviceStatus[]>response.json());` in my component class. Unfortunately this didn't seem to change anything.

Why does it seem like my json object isn't being mapped properly?

My model interface:

```
export interface DeviceStatus {
    deviceId: string;
    modelName: string;
}
```

My component:

```
export class FetchDataComponent {
    public devices: Observable<DeviceStatus[]>;

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.devices =
            http.get('api/Devices')
                .map((response: Response) => <DeviceStatus[]>response.json());

        this.devices.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    }
}
```

The result in Chrome console:

```
(2) [Object, Object]
  0: Object
    DeviceId: "1"
    ModelName: "Model Name"
...
```

Comment: AFAIK, since JavaScript/TypeScript are case sensitive, it won't match "modelName" with "ModelName". When I've run into this before, I fixed it on the server side. I was using ASP.NET at the time and found a JSON Formatter that I could use in my Web API Service that changed the output to camel casing.

Comment: @DeborahK that would be great if I could get my hands on that JSON Formatter. I'm also using ASP.NET on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) only informs the compiler, it does nothing to the actual data as it says in the docs:

> A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, **but performs
>   no special checking or restructuring of data**

Always remember that the type system in typescript doesn't get translated to javascript, so in runtime you don't have that.

You'll need to do the convertion yourself:

```
this.devices =
    http.get('api/Devices')
        .map((response: Response) => response.json().map(device => ({
             deviceId: device.DeviceId,
             modelName: device.ModelName
        }));
```

Comment: Chose this as the accepted answer since my original question mentioned type assertion explicitly and did not specify ASP.NET. Anyone finding this who *is* using ASP.NET though, @DeborahK provided an excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ASP.NET code using the formatter:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver=
  new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

It converts the properties to camel case before returning them in the response.

You can find out more about it here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm

And there is a more complete example in this post here: [Web API 2: how to return JSON with camelCased property names, on objects and their sub-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552567/web-api-2-how-to-return-json-with-camelcased-property-names-on-objects-and-the)