# JSON Camel Case Attribute for Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I have such endpoint in my controller :

```
public async Task<<IEnumerable<ItemsList>>> GetItems()
    {
        List<ItemsList>> items = await _itemManager.GetItemsAsync();       
        return items;
    }
```

And when I get result from this endpoint :

```
{
 "Type": "SomeType",
  "Items":[{"Id":1,"ItemType":"SomeType"}] 
 }
```

but I want to be Camel Case, such as :

```
{
"type": "SomeType",
 "items":[{"id":1,"itemType":"SomeType"}] 
}
```

Here is of

```
public class ItemsList
{
    public ItemType Type { get; set; }
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
}
```

I found solution like :

```
public async Task<<IEnumerable<ItemsList>>> GetItems()
    {
        List<ItemsList>> items = await _itemManager.GetItemsAsync();

         var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
             {
               ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
             };

        return Json(items),serializerSettings);       
    }
```

> So, what I want to do it's to create Attribute, which can be applied to specific endpoint and make result from the endpoint to be camelCase.
>
> Applying Json attributes to Dto's or formatting the whole controller isn't my case.

Comment: put in startup of app : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28553455/1875256

Comment: Do you want camelCase only for this specific endpoint?

Comment: @KirkLarkin, exactly. I don't want to camelCase for whole controller or put attributes on DTO's

Comment: I think the solution you've added to your question is going to be the most appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

On the entity, you can use:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
```

On a property, you can use:

```
[JsonProperty(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
```

Also on a property, you can manually specify the property name if you wish:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "myPropertyName")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the `DataMemberAttribute` from `System.Runtime.Serialization`

Example:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class SomeDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "unitCount")]
    public int UnitCount { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "packagingType")]
    public PackagingType PackagingTypeIdEtc { get; set; }

// ...
```

The output will be camelCase and you'll also be able to control things like `emitDefaultValue` and so on.

```
{
    unitCount: 3,
    packagingType: "box",
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting below in     `Register` function under `WebApiConfig`

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{    
    config.Formatters.Clear();
    config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractresolvder();
}
```