# Configuring WebApi 2.0 such that controller.Json(...) returns camelCaseFormatted data

Tags: configuration, asp.net-web-api2

Consider following piece of some controller's code:

```
return Json(Result.Succeed());
```

Output it produces is `{ "Success": true }`, because underlying model property is declared as `bool Sucess` (uppercase). I'd like `Json(...)` to spit out `camelCaseFormatted` json as it is conventional in the js/typescript world.

So even tought model's property is `S`uccess, I'd like respond to be `s`uccess.

How can I configure that one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web API 2: how to return JSON with camelCased property names, on objects and their sub-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552567/web-api-2-how-to-return-json-with-camelcased-property-names-on-objects-and-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `JsonProperty` attribute on model property as follows:

`[JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }`